# How do I check if a browser supports HTML5 and CSS3 features using Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, browser, html

I need to make an `if` statement using Ruby that checks to see if the client's browser support HTML5 or not.

Comment: have you checked out http://html5test.com/ ? they do a very thorough html feature support check.

Comment: modernizr helps you with this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short version: you won't be able to, nor should you.

Long version: It may be possible, if you do some user-agent sniffing, to identify whether or not the user's browser supports HTML5 or not. But this would take a fair amount of effort to get right. The better solution is to use something like Modernizr (http://www.modernizr.com/) to do your feature detection on the client-side.

Comment: huh?? browser information is sent in the header of the http request!! You can read it through request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] command in ruby on rails, What I want is to know which versions from each famous browsers that can handle most html5 features

Comment: That's my point, you can sniff all you want. However, that's not a guaranteed solution and is in fact a very bad idea compared to the alternatives. Why would you need to check on the server-side anyway?

Comment: It wont be 100% accurate, but I want to make Chrome 5 and above, firefox4, IE12983 and above, opera ?? and above, and safari ?? and above render entirely different layout for my page... I think I answered my own question, thanks for your help

Comment: I would argue that you should still be doing that on the client-side and writing CSS based on the classes Modernizr will insert into your HTML. That way, you can support old and new - progressive enhancement!

Comment: I am revamping the whole page.. it would be easier to support it this way

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to read the browser info based on the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` string, but, as mentioned above and many other places, it's also really easy to spoof that info. On the server-side we only cared because it gave us an overall view of the client browsers being used to access our sites.

Trying to react to a browser on the backend and present different content was tried by sites for a while, but it fails because of how browsers spoof other browsers, but don't have the same bugs.

As @Stephen Orr said, CSS is a better way of dealing with it. Sure it's hell and still error-prone, but it's better than sniffing the browser's signature. We used to cuss every release of IE because it broke the previous fixes. Luckily things seem to be getting better as the vendors creep toward toeing standards.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I think you said parts of that much better than I did.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do [Feature detection](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html) on HTML5, to detect single features from HTML5 as you need them. There is, however, no way to detect if a browser supports HTML5 as one big chunk - as there is no "official" way to tell if a browser supports all of HTML5 or just parts of it.

Answer (score 1):

Most features can be detected (with JavaScript), but some kinds like the form-date-feature field is a problem: http://united-coders.com/matthias-reuter/user-agent-sniffing-is-back

Answer (score 0):

```
< [html5 element]  id="somethingtobedazzledby">
    Upgrade your browser
</ [html5 element] >
```